# How to search a workbook for a value to determine if a page should be updated

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an Excel "database" to track projects; the "database" inputs new records through a VBA window with unique identifiers for each project into an aggregate sheet. There are multiple reports that pull data from the aggregate sheet based on certain parameters.

These parameters do not seem to work as I planned and now I am having trouble coming up with a new "If Statement."

I've already tried using static/ hard coded If Statements to check for values used in the records. However when I try to update projects that are in one report but not another, I get an error.

```
Dim aa As Worksheet
Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Log")
Dim x As Long

If Me.proj_stat_combo.Value = "OPEN PROJECTS (No Current Open SLA)" Then
 y = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.srnew_combo.Value), ak.Range("C:C"), 0)

    aa.Range("B" & xx).Value = Me.fd_reqnum_txt.Value
    aa.Range("C" & xx).Value = Me.srnew_combo.Value
    aa.Range("D" & xx).Value = Me.projdes_txt.Value
    aa.Range("E" & xx).Value = Me.fd_contact_combo.Value
    aa.Range("F" & xx).Value = Me.targetstart.Value
    aa.Range("G" & xx).Value = Me.target_impdate_txt.Value
    aa.Range("H" & xx).Value = Me.load_txt.Value
    aa.Range("I" & xx).Value = Me.irc.Value
    aa.Range("J" & xx).Value = Me.busdays.Value
    aa.Range("K" & xx).Value = Me.priorcomment.Value

End If
```

My hope is the following:

1. Update the VBA window with new project information
2. When I press the update button the code would search each report workbook for the identifier
3. If the identifier is found, the associated record updates
4. If the identifier is not found, the "If Statement" would push the code to search the next report and repeat until there are no longer any reports to look for the identifier

Answer (score 0):

I believe, though it's hard to verify with out some data, your issue is that you're trying to search multiple sheets, but you're only looking at one sheet. Project Log in this case.

You can only update/pull information from Project Log. If the data exists on another sheet; you will error out. It sounds like what you first need to do is search the entire workbook and all the sheets; and based on where you find information dynamically "grab" that worksheet.

You're currently looking at 1 static sheet. Is that your intent?

I've written a rough example below. I have 2 worksheets (Sheet1, Sheet2). 
Sheet1 has no headers. In the first Column is Names, in the Second is something they like. Sheet2 is similar no heads, but in Column 1 is colors, column 2 is objects (Truck, Car, etc).

```
Public Sub main()
Dim bk As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim size As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim counter2 As Long
Dim find As String
Dim found As String

Dim shtName(1) As String
size = 3
shtName(0) = "Sheet1"
shtName(1) = "Sheet2"

Set bk = ThisWorkbook

find = "John"

For counter2 = 0 To 1

    For counter = 1 To size
        If bk.Sheets(shtName(counter2)).Cells(counter, 1).Value2 = find Then
            found = bk.Sheets(shtName(counter2)).Cells(1, 2).Value2
        End If
    Next counter
Next counter2



End Sub
```

There's many ways to do this, depending on your knowledge of VBA. I created a 2 element string array and stored my worksheet names on those. I then looped through those worksheets, and each row of column 1 of those worksheets.

This code with my setup makes found = Jazz.

This should get you started on dynamically searching worksheets.

Comment: To answer your question, the process is to press an update button that will pop up an input window. In the window, there is a drop down to select an identifier unique to the record. I am hoping to figure out a way to have the macro search through each report (8 reports in total) for the identifier chosen and update each record in each different report where the identifier is found.    Right now each report has its own unique format for their general use; so the macro would need to update each record where an identifier was found and update the values in the correct fields. I've updated my code

Comment: Sorry, work got a bit busy. So let me make sure I understand the structure of your reports. Your workbook contains 8 reports (Sheets) in total. When the user presses a button you want a user form to pop up and them to enter/select a unique ID. Once they select an ID and do some "work" you want to update all reports that unique ID is on. However, each workbook has different formatting for columns, Name might be column A in one, B in another, and D on another.

Is that correct? If so, I'll create an Excel workbook that mimics this as closely as possible and write for that.